# myisam_sort_buffer_size vs sort_buffer_size

Tags: mysql, sorting, buffer

I am MySQL on server with 6GB RAM. I need to know what is the difference between myisam_sort_buffer_size and sort_buffer_size?

I have following size set to them:

myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

sort_buffer_size = 256M

Please also mention if these values are fine or need adjustments?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**sort_buffer_size:**

MySQL documentation:

> Each session that needs to do a sort allocates a buffer of this size. sort_buffer_size is not specific to any storage engine and applies in a general manner for optimization.

Your sort_buffer_size value seems extremely high.  The default is 2M.  I'd recommend going no larger than that since there is a performance penalty for going higher.  [Some people recommend smaller values](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/more-on-understanding-sort_buffer_size-2010-05-10/) such as 256kB.  One thing to remember is this is per-client-session, it's not a global value.  Large values will add up fast.

**myisam_sort_buffer_size:**

MySQL documentation:

> The size of the buffer that is allocated when sorting MyISAM indexes during a REPAIR TABLE or when creating indexes with CREATE INDEX or ALTER TABLE.

Your myisam_sort_buffer_size seems fine.  This won't be relevant unless you are rebuilding indexes using ALTER TABLE or REPAIR TABLE etc.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, you mentioned that my sort_buffer_size is too high. Can you please let me know the optimal size since I am doing lot of sorts?

Comment: There are some more tuning parameters. I think we should mention here about them so other people get benefit from this:
tmp_table_size = 64M, 
key_buffer_size = 768M, 
read_rnd_buffer_size = 6M, 
table_cache = 800. 

Can you please say some words about these values for server with 6GB RAM and high traffic.
Thanks

Comment: I'd leave sort_buffer_size at 2M.

Comment: For the other tunables, it also depends on if the server is dedicated to MySQL only, if you use MyISAM or InnoDB or a combination (I'm guessing you use MyISAM), how many tables you have, etc.  It might be worth looking to see if these have already been addressed in other questions, or asking a new question if not.  I think most of these sound ok but it depends as I said.  MySQL also provide sample configuration files.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your replies. If you could mention some URLs where I can find information specifically about mysql performance tuning. I know there are bunch of sites but I could not find answers to my questions like, working with indexes, which fields should be included in index, what is max table size, how number of tables affect performance etc etc. It seems I need a full book that covers all performance areas :-)

Comment: @D3K: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/10/25/impact-of-the-sort-buffer-size-in-mysql/

Comment: @D3K: Also http://varokism.blogspot.pt/2011/12/fine-tuning-readrndbuffersize-and.html

Comment: Also consider sort_buffer_size when managing your maximum threads and memory as per `key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads=memory used`

Answer (score 1):

These arguments is per thread, so check out the number of max_connections.

I.e. with 15GB of RAM

```
max_connections        = 1500
sort_buffer_size = 32M
```

I'm getting mysqltuner warning:

```
 [--] Total buffers: 928.0M global + 32.7M per thread (1500 max threads)
 [!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 48.8G (312% of installed RAM)
```

So I did lower it to the default value.

Comment: and the speed has increased or not?

Comment: I was more optimizing for number of simultanous threads and that each thread has enough memory to run optimally. (I don't know what each thread could allocate altough). I wanted to support approx. 2500 hits per second on a webserver.

Comment: I meant overall number of threads. All my threads are creates by single user (glassfish).

Answer (score 0):

sort_buffer_size =256K
 is best.you try this and restart the mysql server and monitor for few hours you can easily notice the benefit

Comment: Please explain why 256K. Are you quoting the exact same reason as http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/more-on-understanding-sort_buffer_size-2010-05-10/ ?